# How do I get read/write access to folders Windows typically uses while in Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, windows

I recently set up a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu. Ubuntu has a small partition, and my original plan was to store everything I want to download on Ubuntu in the much larger shared partition. However, trying to move a file from /home/Downloads to /Users/me/Downloads does nothing. Therefore, I want to be able to read and write to folders like the Downloads and Documents folders Windows use while on Ubuntu, and vice versa.

I have tried changing the permissions of the entire shared partition to read/write, and just changing /Users/me/Downloads' permissions. Neither of those worked. I'd greatly appreciate help.

Comment: Look into using Samba

Comment: In any dual-boot with Windows disabling Fast Startup is a MUST. That automatically "solves" the issue (it's not about permissions, NTFS do NOT support such settings). However... **It's a very bad idea to write to the Windows SYSTEM partition from outside Windows**. You can have a NTFS additional data partition shared between OSes to do what you want, just DON'T use the Windows system partition for that. Most of the times nothing happens but occasionally Windows won't boot.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the permissions right should make it possible for you to read and write to a partition shared with windows, i.e., most likely a partition formatted with the ntfs file system.

So first check whether the drive is correctly mounted and visible. Also report in more detail what happens when you attempt to move files. "does nothing" does not provide very much information on how you tried to move, and how the system reacted on the move.

A very common cause of the impossibility to write to an ntfs partition is that the file system is **in an inconsistent state**. If that is the case, linux will mount the file system read only, or even refuse to mount it at all.

You therefore need to make sure that the file system **is in a consistent state** before starting linux.

- Boot into Windows
- **Turn off fast start** - this is what causes Windows to leave a partition in an inconsistent state during shut down - it is one of the tricks to speed up the startup. Turn this off if you share a drive with another OS.
- Have the drive checked and repaired using the Windows tools
- **Fully** shut down Windows (each time, no hibernate or sleep state) before starting linux.

That will make sure the ntfs file system is "clean" before linux attempts to mount it.

**1) Correct an ntfs drive that is not "clean"**

Start up in Windows. Have the drive checked and repaired

Comment: Yes, the drive is visible with Nautilus, and I can view every folder in it. As for moving files to that partition, well, does nothing is really all I can say. It does not let me move a file. If I copy a file, it won't let me paste it. If I drag a file between two windows, it won't copy to the destination. It's like I never copied something in the first place.

I turned off Fast Start, repaired the device and fully shut down before booting into Ubuntu. It works perfectly fine now. Many thanks!